# How can I make a system-modal window?

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, kiosk

Is it possible to make the **main form** of an application **system modal**? My application will FTP a file from a remote company PC. Users should not be allowed to interact with the desktop while this process is in progress.

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.ShowMainForm := False;
...
FormChild.ShowModal;
```

Comment: Having a modal form means you won't be able to interact with the forms behind it. There is no form behind the main form, hence I fail to see the point.

Comment: There is only one form in the application. I need to prevent users from interacting with the desktop for as long as my application is running. Users are on remote pc's connected to the company network.

Comment: @Pieter You can't do this. You shouldn't even try. Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @Pieter The best you can do is to show a message saying "Don't interact with the desktop".

Comment: This application is not for 'general use'. I need to ftp a file from a remote company pc back to HO. I need to prevent users from interacting with the desktop while this process is in progress. I will also display a message 'Do not ...'.

Comment: Have you considered installing cattle prods alongside the remote PCs?

Comment: Why don't you make the file transfer work independantly of the user being remote-desktopped into the computer?

Comment: You don't want modality, you want "kiosk mode". In which case, you should look into dWinLock by KASSL.

Comment: @Warren Of course, he'll have to ban 64 bit Windows too if he uses that dWinLock!

Comment: Pieter, by now you've realized that even if you could have a simple modal window — even by hiding the main form and making another window modal — you wouldn't have accomplished what you set out to do. Andreas was correct to mention the concept of *system modal*, which is what you need if you want to prevent access to other programs. Even an ordinary modal child window would only be modal with respect to your application (which would be pointless because there wouldn't be any other windows to block access to). I've edited your question to make it ask for what you really want.

Comment: Rob. Thank you. I did not expect my question to raise such a heated debate! I think a main window with a modal child dialog window on top would suffice. Regards.

Comment: @Pieter: good you came to your conclusion so fast. Imposing a system-wide limitation on your users is so last century :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to make the main form modal. Indeed, if you have an ordinary application with a (normal) main form, and then displays a modal form (e.g. a dialog box, or a `TOpenDialog`), then the "modality" means that the main form, and the rest of **your** application, becomes "disabled" until the modal form is closed. (But other applications aren't affected at all by this.) But this doesn't make sense for the main form, because when the main form is shown, there is no "rest" of your application to disable. In fact, a normal main form is in a sense already modal, if you do not open any other forms.

I think that you wish to create a *system modal* form, that is, a form that disables **the rest of the desktop** when shown. But this isn't too easy to do, because of the security principles of modern versions of the Microsoft Windows operating system. Indeed, a single application isn't (normally) supposed to take control over the entire OS like this.

Comment: +1. Still, judging from the sample code it seems like the OP wants modality at the application level, on which point you have been clear enough, I guess.

Comment: We want to retrieve files from a remote computer, ie. deploy a executable that starts at a specific time and then FTP's a file or files back home. While this is in progress, I do not want users to interact with the desktop. I therefore need to main form to be modal. Regards.

Comment: For this task I would make e.g. borderless maximized form with gray screenshot from the rest of the desktop and in the center of this form some progress bar or whatever you want to be active. But consider very carefully to prevent user switching between the other applications. And I would say, CTRL + ALT + DEL is always enabled.

Comment: Yes I'm going to press CTRL+ALT+DELETE, I'm going to select task manager, I'm going to Click File | Run and then I'll run `pskill IrritatingPseudoKioskApp`. Actually I'd just kill the app before it even started attempting any of this nonsense!

Comment: But still you can poke out the keys from your keyboard :)

Comment: Or even better is to use your own keyboard communicating e.g. through the USB / COM directly to your application by your own way.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own desktop using `CreateDesktop()` (and create a status window to display on it), then use `OpenDesktop()` to retreive the user's desktop, then switch between them using `SwitchDesktop()` when the file transfer begins and ends.  While your custom desktop is active, the user cannot access his/her desktop (the screensaver does exactly this, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention that you want to do is difficult to comprehend as modal form's purpose is to disable all application forms below so basically application form might be considered a modal form itself.

Although if you wish to make your application the only receiver of focus on current windows desktop (possibly non-administrative user desktop), you need to:

1. Hide the taskbar by making your form fullscreen
2. Lock as many windows keys as you can afford considering accessibility of your application (Ctrl, Alt, F1-F12, Windows, Menu)

With new versions of windows you can do all of that as non-priviledged user, except Ctrl+Alt+Del combination using global window hooks.

```
uses
  Windows;

var
  hKeybaordHook: HHOOK = 0;

function KeyboardHook(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): HRESULT; stdcall;
type
  PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = packed record
    vkCode: DWORD;
    scanCode: DWORD;
    flags: DWORD;
    time: DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo: DWORD;
  end;
const
  LLKHF_ALTDOWN = $20;
var
  pkbhs: PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
  pkbhs := PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam);
  if nCode = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    Result := 1;
// CTRL
    if WordBool(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) and $8000) then Exit
// ALT
    else if LongBool(pkbhs^.flags and LLKHF_ALTDOWN) then Exit
// WIN KEYS
    else if (pkbhs^.vkCode = VK_LWIN) or (pkbhs^.vkCode = VK_RWIN) then Exit
// FUNCTION KEYS
    else if bDisableFunctionKeys and (pkbhs^.vkCode >= VK_F1) and (pkbhs^.vkCode <= VK_F24) then Exit;
{
// Disabling specific combinations
// CTRL+ESC
    else if (pkbhs^.vkCode = VK_ESCAPE) and WordBool(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) and $8000) then Exit
// ALT+TAB
    else if (pkbhs^.vkCode = VK_TAB) and LongBool(pkbhs^.flags and LLKHF_ALTDOWN) then Exit
// ALT+ESC
    else if (pkbhs^.vkCode = VK_ESCAPE) and LongBool(pkbhs^.flags and LLKHF_ALTDOWN) then Exit
}
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hKeybaordHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure MainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
const
  WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
begin
  SetBounds(0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height);

  if hKeybaordHook = 0 then
    hKeybaordHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @KeyboardHook, HInstance, 0);
end;

procedure MainForm.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (hKeybaordHook <> 0) and UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeybaordHook) then
    hKeybaordHook := 0;
end;
```

You can also set "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe" registry key value to some dummy text, to disable task manager (including Ctrl+Shift+Esc combination).

Comment: This kind of software is known as malware

Comment: But genuine applications using such modus operandi are known as kiosk applications. Take a look at the nearest ATM or information kiosk.

Comment: My atm does not run windows. A real kiosk doesn't run explorer as its shell.

Comment: I agree shell should not be run on any kiosk yet kiosk mode of an application should not disable windows shell permanently as well.

Comment: you can't just switch from desktop mode to kiosk mode

Comment: @Robert You don't get that in this country (UK)! I'm sure there are no ATMs running Windows here and I'm sure there never will be!

Comment: @too You see Windows kiosks all the time in lots of places, but not ATMs in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to take over the user's desktop and prevent them from using their computer, you could use [dWinLock](http://www.kassl.de/winlock/download.shtml).

Comment: Until we get a 64 bit delphi, anyways. :-)