# delphi Freeze Screen on windows

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog

Is there any way to freeze the screen and show only one form active (only that form can receive input from user).

The example of my description is like when windows user clicks shutdown from start menu. It shows choices like shutdown, restart, etc and not allows user to do input other than to that form.
or when using Tune Up registry optimizer it will ask you to close all other running applications , then it shows up a Blue Window with a progress bar , but the user can neither close this window or do other input .

I know about modal forms , but is there any other way to do that .

Any Idea?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: What behaviour do you want that ShowModal won't give you? Fr instance Tune up, does let you do other input, otherwise you wouldn't be able to close the applications it said you have to....

Comment: Are you trying to make a kiosk application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually stop input to other apps you probably need to use SetWindowsHookEx() to install a global message hook (I think you want to use the WH_CBT option) in order to toss messages sent to other windows (of course you're going to need Admin. privileges to do that).

*However*, there's another way: a) have your program take a screenshot of the display, b) post-process the bitmap to "gray" it out, and c) show your application completely full-screen (there's easy methods of sizing the app to overwrite even the taskbar) and your set your app form's background to be the screenshot you took in step A and grayed-out in step B. What you wind up with is a simple image display that looks quite like the user's desktop, but the windows are of course not clickable.

Comment: But when you won't steal me a keyboard, I'll still be able to *hack* your application ;-)

Comment: TLama: It wouldn't be *my* app 'cause I know better than to try: You can't capture Ctrl-Alt-Del without writing your own GINA dll loaded at logon. Alt-Tab you *can* capture with a hook, but...so what? If I'm kept from Alt-Tabbing out of an app, I'll just use Ctrl-Alt-Del to pop up the task manager and kill the process. So why bother hooking the keyboard?

Comment: Anyways, this discussion is basically a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028944/how-can-i-make-a-system-modal-window?rq=1

Comment: Rather than taking a screenshot of the user's desktop and manipulating it, a simpler approach would be to set the background color of the full-screen Form to a solid grey and then make it translucent via the Form's `AlphaBlendValue` property. The user's actual dekstop will show through, but still appear masked out and be unclickable.

Comment: @Erik your comments about GINA are way out of date, it died with Vista

Comment: Thanks David. I'm starting to think *I'm* way out of date. Is it possible to grab Ctrl-Alt-Del anymore?

Comment: @Remy -- that's a great idea! Much easier than my suggestion.

Comment: @Erik, as from I've seen no, you can either run OS in so called kiosk mode or poke out one of those keys from your keyboard :-)